# Cannot use xdotool to send key to gqrx

Tags: raspbian, xorg, gnuradio

The following works perfectly on my desktop debian:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --classname gqrx windowactivate key ctrl+d
```

It will activate the window of gqrx and synthetically hit ctrl+d, starting the dsp. On the Pi (Pi 3, Raspbian Jessie), this does activate the window, but the key press is not registered, at least the application doesn't react. I also tried keydown, keyup, windowfocus.

Answer (score 1):

I seems the event chaining doesn't work, even when using the `--delay` switch for the `key` command. Issuing two separate commands works:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool search --onlyvisible --classname gqrx windowactivate
sleep 1
xdotool key ctrl+d
```